# Validar usuario existente

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Cuando preparo esta consulta, quiero que en el if se valide si el usuario existe o no, y para eso uso "mysqli_num_rows()". El problema es que si lo hago sin preparar la consulta, metiendo la consulta a pelo (está comentada en el código), funciona. Pero preparándola no tengo muy claro cómo es.

El error que me da es este:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\wamp\www\servidor...\validacion.php on line 36

código conexion_bd.php:

```html
<?php

 session_start();

 $db_conexion="localhost";
 $db_usuario="root";
 $db_pass="";
 $db_nombre="ciclos";

 //Conexión con mysqli procedural
 $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_conexion, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre);

 mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

 if(!$conexion) {

  die("Error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
?>
```

Y el código:

```html
<?php

 require_once("conexion_bd.php");

 //Validar usuario con mysqli procedural
 if(isset($_POST["entrar"])){

  $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["usuario_entrar"];
  $_SESSION["contra"]=$_POST["contra_entrar"];

  $usuario_entrar=$_SESSION["usuario"];
  $contra_entrar=$_SESSION["contra"];

  if($usuario_entrar=="" || $contra_entrar=="") { 

    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro.')</script>");

  }else{


   //$resultado_entrar1=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario_entrar' AND contrasenha='$contra_entrar'");
   $resultado_entrar=mysqli_prepare($conexion, "SELECT usuario, contrasenha FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasenha=?");
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado_entrar, "ss", $usuario_entrar, $contra_entrar);
   mysqli_execute($resultado_entrar);
   mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado_entrar, $usuario_entrar, $contra_entrar);
   //mysqli_close($resultado_entrar);
   //mysqli_close($conexion);

   if ($resultado_entrar===false){

    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion));
    die();

   }else{

    $verificacion_entrar=mysqli_num_rows($resultado_entrar);


    if($verificacion_entrar>0){

     header('Location: contenido.php');

    }else{

     echo("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
    }
   }
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: es un warning. Probaste si tiene datos tu $resultado_entrar??

Comment: Checa con esta pregunta SO en ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761992/mysqli-num-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-object

Comment: @josego No entendí muy bien lo de si tiene datos. Si le llegan los valores que introduzco en las variables? Sí, no sé si eso eso lo que me dices.

Comment: @J.Castro Ya probé orientado a objetos y tampoco me funcionaba...

Comment: @jopimar si tiene resultados me refiero. Hace un print_r($resultado_entrar) para ver si te salen datos

Comment: @josego Me imprime esto: `mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 2 [field_count] => 2 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 ) Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.`

Comment: @jopimar si te fijas en lo que te imprime vas a ver que te dice  [num_rows] => 0 Osea 0 resultados. Ademas dice Usuario o o contraseña incorrectos. Verifica tu consulta. Algo esta mal

Comment: Proba esto. 

    $resultado_entrar1=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=$usuario_entrar AND contrasenha=$contra_entrar");

Comment: @josego Claro, así sí que me funciona, pero lo que yo quiero es tener una consulta preparada: No sé si me explico, poniéndolo así, es como lo tengo comentado en el código.

Comment: @jopimar podrias incluir tu archivo require_once("conexion_bd.php");  Así veo de probar y adaptar

Comment: @josego Lo acabo de añadir.

Comment: @jopimar coloque los dos códigos para que pruebes en tu equipo. Debería de funcionar. Avisame y adaptamos eso, porque en mi equipo si funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo seguiría el manual de PHP y cambiaría ciertas cosas, como mysqli_execute($resultado_entrar) por mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado_entrar) ya que ese alias está obsoleto y si actualizas PHP, esa línea quedaría inservible, checalo [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-execute.php).
También usaría mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resultado_entrar) en vez de mysqli_num_rows($resultado_entrar) y antes de esto mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado_entrar) [manual mysqli_stmt_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Espero que eso ayude.

Comment: Pues sí, el fallo era ese que acabas de comentar. Solucionado entonces. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `$verificacion_entrar = $resultado_entrar->num_rows();` en lugar de `$verificacion_entrar=mysqli_num_rows($resultado_entrar);` 
Antes también has esto: `$resultado_entrar->bind-param("ss"....` y luego `$resultado_entrar->execute()`

Comment: Ya probé y ya no salta ningún error, warning ni nada pero tampoco se cumple la condición del if. Pasa al else directamente.

Comment: Intenta con lo nuevo que agregué. Creo que debes tratarlo con orientado o objetos

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo Necesitas un validacion de Login, espero te sirva el que utilizo
//Formulario de las Credenciales

```
    <form action="php/comprobar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="div-login-msg">
           <div id="icon-login-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
           <span id="text-login-msg">Ingrese Sus Datos de Acceso</span>
        </div>
            <input id="usuario_nombre" name="usuario_nombre" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Numero de Empleado" required><br>
            <input id="usuario_clave" name="usuario_clave" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Apellido Paterno" required>
          <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox"> Recordar
             </label>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="ingresar" value="Ingresar">
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Archivo de Validación

```
<?php

        session_start();
        include('conexion.php');
        if(isset($_POST['ingresar']))
           {
              if(empty($_POST['usuario_nombre']) || empty($_POST['usuario_clave']))
              {
                  echo "El usuario o la contraseña no han sido ingresados. <a href='javascript:history.back();'>Reintentar</a>";
              }
            else
            {
                  $usuario_nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST['usuario_nombre']);
                  $usuario_clave = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn,$_POST['usuario_clave']);
                  $usuario_nombre= md5($usuario_nombre); //En esta parte Encripto los datos de Acceso
                  $usuario_clave = md5($usuario_clave);
                  $sqlprofesor = mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT usuario_id, usuario_numero, usuario_apellido FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_numero='".$usuario_nombre."' AND usuario_apellido='".$usuario_clave."'");
                  if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlprofesor))
                  {
                  $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['usuario_id'];
                  $_SESSION['admin'] = $row["usuario_numero"];
                  $_SESSION['last_login_timestamp'] = time();
                  $usuario=$row["usuario_numero"];
                  echo "<script> alert('Acceso Correcto');window.location.href = '../admin'</script>";
              }
                else
                    {
                echo "<script> alert(' Error Reintentar');window.location.href = '../index.php'</script>";
                }
          }
        }
        else
          {
              echo "<script> alert(' Error Reintentar');</script>";
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }
    ?>
```

Para validar cada uno de los Formularios

```
<?php
include("../php/conexion.php");
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
   if (!isset($_SESSION["admin"]) || $_SESSION["admin"] == "") {
 redirect("../php/logout.php");
 }
?>
```

En este parte tu codigo si el usuario ingreso correctamente

```
 <?php 
  }else {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: usa mysqli con sentencias preparadas, mejor PDO, no uses md5() y hay algún que otro fallos en tú código

Comment: @aldanux Estoy de acuerdo contigo en las setencias preparadas pero porque no MD5?

Comment: Porque es inseguro... [leer más](http://php.net/manual/es/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) mejor usa [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

Comment: @aldanux Muchas Gracias.. he leido el archivo, espero poder editar mi respuesta con el uso de Procedimientos Almacenados

Comment: @Jopimar ......

Answer (score 0):

Utilice el objeto mysqli

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $db_conexion="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_pass="";
    $db_nombre="ciclos";

    // Crea conexion.
    $conexion= new mysqli($db_conexion, $db_usuario, $db_pass, $db_nombre);

    // Checkear conexion.
    if($conexion->connect_error) {
        die("Error de conexión: " . $conexion->connect_error);
    }
?>

<?php

    require_once("conexion_bd.php");

    //Validar usuario con mysqli procedural
    if(isset($_POST["entrar"])){

        $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["usuario_entrar"];
        $_SESSION["contra"]=$_POST["contra_entrar"];

        $usuario_entrar=$_SESSION["usuario"];
        $contra_entrar=$_SESSION["contra"];

        if($usuario_entrar=="" || $contra_entrar=="") { 

                echo("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro.')</script>");

        }else{


            //$resultado_entrar1=mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario_entrar' AND contrasenha='$contra_entrar'");
            $resultado_entrar = $conexion->prepare("SELECT usuario, contrasenha FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasenha=?");
            $resultado_entrar->bind_param("ss", $usuario_entrar, $contra_entrar);
            $resultado_entrar->execute();
            //mysqli_close($resultado_entrar);
            //mysqli_close($conexion);

            $resultado_entrar->store_result();

            if ($resultado_entrar===false){
                die("Error: " . $conexion->connect_error);
            }else{

                $verificacion_entrar = $resultado_entrar->num_rows;


                if($verificacion_entrar>0){

                    header('Location: contenido.php');

                }else{

                    echo("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Debería de funcionarte. Probé en mi maquina y funciona.